# Programmatically select menu item for mvvm prism application using Telerik RadMenu

Tags: mvvm, telerik

Hello I have a prism/mvvm style application and am using the RadMenu control. I also have a view/view model pair in one project and another view/view model pair for my RadMenu control in another project. Basically I would like to use the event aggregator to send an event to the view model for the RadMenu (the view model that is paired with the view that the RadMenu sits inside of). So that the RadMenu's view model can notify the RadMenu to switch to a different RadMenuItem programmatically. I think I can use a blend behavior to contain the behavior I'm looking to reproduce, but I cannot find a method in the RadMenu that will allow me to programmatically select a specific menu item.

If the control does not support this now, is there a work around? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a missunderstanding. As far as I know there is no selection on the RadMenu. You can only Check or Uncheck Items in your Menus. Are you trying to emulate a user clicking on a specific item just to trigger the functionality behind the menu-item? If that's the case I would propose another way and directly handle the EA-Message in the ViewModel. You can trigger the code from there then. If you're doing MVVM the logic behind the menu-items is implented in your VM anyways. :)

Comment: Thanks what I'm trying to do is show one of the menu items that live in one module (and therefore view/view model pair), when someone clicks on a panel in another module. I know I can use the ea to pass event messages around. But its that last piece of triggering the actual desired menu item that has me wondering how. According to telerik I can use a property called IsCurrent, but I'll have to try it. Any other suggestions and code samples are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: In my understanding the RadMenu is generally collapsed. Something triggers a message handled by your ViewModel. Then you want to expand and show the menu? I guessed you actually wanted to trigger the code behind the menu-item. What you see when using your mouse in the menu is propably just a hover effect, not a selection. There is no sense (visible to me) in having selections in a menu.
So once more: Do you want to invoke something after the message arrives or do you want to just indicate (expand menu f.e.) something happend?